# How to assign jquery to TempData in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want when `click` on the `button` put a value into temdata .I use this code but after page  load  I check inspector and found that this function don't assigned to the button. I think that when browser load this code get error.How to fix this?

```
$('#Continue').click(function (e) {
    if (!$('#SweepFlight').is(':checked')) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        validateDeparturef(e);
    }//if !checked
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ($('#SweepFlight').is(':checked')) {
       // e.preventDefault();
        validateDeparturef(e);
        validateArrivalf(e);
    }//if checked

    @TempData["DepAvailClassCode"] = $('#Departuref article.show + div.detailFlight div.btn.backGreen').val();
    @TempData["ArrAvailClassCode"] = $('#Arrivalf article.show + div.detailFlight div.btn.backGreen').val();

});//click
```

Comment: Simple answer is __You can't.__

Comment: No you cannot do this. `TempData` is server side code. You cannot set it from the client unless you pass the value to the server using ajax (or submit a form/pass it in a link)

Comment: After I click on the this button my form submit

Comment: "After I click on the this button my form submit" - you set your `TempData` variables in the controller/action that is handling your form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `TempData` works current and the subsequent requests only, you can try to pass the value from View to Controller first and then from the Controller to the same or another View with the help of TempData, ViewBag or ViewData etc.

***View I:***

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Departure", new { classCode = departure.DepAvailClassCode })
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult Update([Bind(Exclude = null)] DepartureModel departure)
{   
    //...
    TempData["clsCode"] = departure.DepAvailClassCode;
    //or
    TempData["clsCode"] = departure.classCode
{
```

***View II:***

```
var value = @TempData["clsCode"]
```

For the differences between ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData you might have a look at [When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't do that.

TempData is a property of ControllerBase class.TempData is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request (means redirecting from one page to another).It’s life is very short and lies only till the target view is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Tempdata is Controller to Controoler or Action to Action not works for View to Action so simply you can't do it.